# Background image command works in twocolumn article but not in memoir

Tags: memoir, two-column, backgrounds

The following example works fine and places my chosen background image correctly:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{
  \put(0in,-\paperheight){%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{imagefilename}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

If I switch from `article` to `memoir` then I get the following error:

```
! A <box> was supposed to be here.
```

On the other hand, it does work if `memoir` is used without `twocolumn`.

Does anybody know the cause/fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus is due to `memoir` loading the `mparhack` package in `twocolumn` mode as else the placement of margin stuff cannot always the trusted (as the mechanism to determine whether we are in first or second column cannot always be trusted.

Sadly `mparhack` has a bad interaction with the kernel hooks when in `twocolumn` mode. It also happens in `book`

You can *disable* the `mparhack` loading via

```
\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{mparhack}{}
\makeatother
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
```

I'll need to reconsider whether we should keep on loading `mparhack` in twocolumn mode and instead let users load it themself if needed.

As mentioned in this other thread about the issue this is caused by `mparhack` changing a macro they should not be changing. Especially `\includegraphics` does not like that change. To survive with `mparhack` store the image in a box and then use the box.

```
\newsavebox\mybox
\sbox\mybox{\includegraphics....}
...
\usebox\mybox
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but perhaps it might help someone else to come up with one.

```
% memimageprob.tex  SE 636170

%\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
%\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{mwe}  %% among other things, provides images

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{
  \put(0in,-\paperheight){%
%    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{imagefilename}}}
    %%% use an image available to everyone
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

All worked fine with the `article` class.

With `\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}` got `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)` but after typing `q` got the two pdf pages as hoped for.

With `\documentclass{memoir}` all processed with no problems.

I never got `A <box> was supposed to be here`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was unaware of the `mwe` package.   Your version does still give me the `A <box> was supposed to be here` error.  This is running TeXlive in MacOS within a `terminal` window.

Comment: @MartynQuick I have just done `tlmgr update --all` to get my system right up to date and still got the result I noted in my answer. I use a Linux OS.

Comment: You are correct.  After updating, I now get `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)` as my error.

Comment: A further update: I've tried use `eso-pic` to place the background image and this gives the same error with twocolumn memoir.